# set flash crossdomain.xml to allow only SSL connections?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, security, crossdomain.xml

How do I set the flash crossdomain.xml file to only allow https ssl secured connections? I  have this but I think this will allow non secure connections too.

< cross-domain-policy >
< allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" / >
< /cross-domain-policy >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the example below, simply change secure="false" to secure="true" to only allow secure SSL connections.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="true" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleFlashSecurityCrossDomain

Comment: What if my settings already have to-ports="80"? Do I have to change it to to-port="443", too. Or simply remove the to-ports attribute?